# How to get textbox value in Code.GS file from HTML page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a spreadsheet and am writing code to integrate with Twitter API. In my sheet, I have two files:

- Code.gs
- settingpage.html

I have some global variables on code.gs i.e  CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET. I want to set these two variables when the user enters a value into textbox and hits the save button.

Textboxes are placed under sidebar. Sidebar is generated from settingpage.html using (HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)

Let me know if am doing it wrong, or of any other way to set global variable value entered by user.

**Code.gs**

```
CONSUMER_KEY    = "Your key value";
CONSUMER_SECRET = "Your key value";

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('BOT')
  .addItem('Setting-config','fnShowSidebar')
  .addItem('Start', 'StartCP')
   .addSeparator()
   .addItem('Stop', 'StopCP')
   .addToUi();
}

function fnShowSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('settingpage')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setTitle('Welcome to TwitterBot-RWT!')
     .setWidth(300);

       SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);
}
```

**settingpage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">

<style>

.centerAlign {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width:80%;
  margin-top:10px;
}

.branding-below {
  bottom: 56px;
  top: 0;
}

</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("#btn_save").click(function(){

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).fn_setCustomValue();
});

function onSuccess(){
 // Logger.log("Success!");
}
</script>

  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="block form-group">
  <label for="city">CONSUMER_KEY</label>
   <input id="txt_CONSUMER_KEY" type="text" value="" style="width: 150px;" />
</div>
   <div class="block form-group">
  <label for="city">CONSUMER_SECRET</label>
   <input id="txt_CONSUMER_SECRET" type="text" value="" style="width: 150px;">
</div>
<div class="block">
     <button id="btn_save" class="create">Save</button> <button>Cancel</button>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**Edited:**

**HTML**

```
<button id="btn_save" class="create">Save</button> 
    <button>Cancel</button>
  </div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(function() {

      var buttonEl=document.getElementById("btn_save");
      buttonEl.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

      function myFunction() {
          alert ("Hello World!");
          var keyValue=document.getElementById("txt_CONSUMER_KEY").value;
          var secretValue=document.getElementById("txt_CONSUMER_SECRET").value;
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).fn_setCustomValue(keyValue,secretValue);
      }

      function onSuccess(){
           Logger.log("Success!");
      }
    });
    </script>
```

On button click i get this screen 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you run fn_setCustomValue you need to pass  the values as an argument, you can do that with document.getItemById(). 
Something along the lines of:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).fn_setCustomValue(document.getElementById("txt_CONSUMER_KEY").value, document.getElementById("txt_CONSUMER_SECRET").value);
```

With fn_setCustomValue() within Code.gs being something along the lines of

```
function fn_setCustomValue(key, secret){
  CONSUMER_KEY = key;
  CONSUMER_SECRET = secret;
}
```

Comment: I tried what you said, but still its now working. Also instead of using document.getItemId("") have used document.getElementbyId("") still now solved. Well on button click i open a new tab pls check the screenshot have added above

Comment: You are right, of course it would be getElementById. value is a propertym not a method of an element, what happens if you remove the brackes? Sorry, I wrote that post on my phone and didn't double check

Comment: After using getElementById() its still not working. on button click it open a new tab as shown in above screenshot

Comment: Did you try value instead of value()?

Comment: Yes i tried using `.value` , every time i hit button don't now why new tab window gets open

Comment: Maybe this has something to do with jquery. Maybe try moving the called function into the button as opposed to an eventlistener. Such as <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="google.script.run.fn_setCustomValue(document.getElementById('txt_CONSUMER_KEY').value,document.getElementById('txt.CONSUMER_SECRET').value)"/>